# Local database setup in combination with staging server database

Tags: 8, database, acquia-dev-desktop

- I have a central remote Git repo (Bonobo git server) where I track
  all the Drupal 8 code etc.
- We have a staging server already up and running installed with
  Drupal 8.
- I cloned the remote repository locally

I want to use Acquia Dev desktop to develop the site locally. But how do I have to use the database setup? So it's somehow related with the staging database. What are best practices for this? Do I have to create a different database in Acquia Dev desktop? When I add configuration and add nodes locally. How do I get this on my staging server?